# sed seems to match pattern properly only when newline inserted

Tags: sed

I am currently running the following sed command:

```
sed 's/P(\(.*\))\\mid(\(.*\))/\\condprob{\1}{\2}/g' myfile.tex
```

Essentially, I have inherited an oddly formatted tex file, and want to replace everything like this:

```
P(<foo>)\mid(<bar>)
```

With this

```
\condprob{<foo>}{<bar>}
```

The file I am trying to run sed on contains the following line:

```
P(\vec{m}_i)\mid(t,h,\alpha) = \prod_{u\in\mathcal{U}} P(\vec{m}_{iu})\mid(t,h,\alpha)
```

Which I would like to change to this:

```
\condprob{\vec{m}_i}{t,h,\alpha} = \prod_{u\in\mathcal{U}}\condprob{\vec{m}_{iu}}{t,h,\alpha}
```

However, sed keeps missing the first \mid and instead gives me this:

```
\condprob{\vec{m}_i)\mid(t,h,\alpha) = \prod_{u\in\mathcal{U}} P(\vec{m}_{iu}}{t,h,\alpha}
```

If I add a line break at the = sign it matches everything fine

Can someone please a) help me resolve this, and b) perhaps tell me why it is happening?

Thanks.

Edit: thanks choroba and Sloopjon, you've both answered my why, and Sloopjon's solution is actually exactly what I was needing. choroba: I guess I will have to wait another day to learn perl.

For those that are interested Sloopjon's solution when translated into my problem looks like this (match everything that isn't a closing parenthesis):

```
sed 's/P(\([^)]*\))\\mid(\([^)]\))/\\condprob{\1}{\2}/g' myfile.tex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you expect `P(\(.*\))` to match only `P(\vec{m}_i)`, but the `*` quantifier is *greedy*, so it actually matches `P(\vec{m}_i)\mid...P(\vec{m}_{iu})`.  There are two common fixes for this: use a non-greedy quantifier if your tool supports it, or change the pattern so that it only matches what you expect.  For example, if you know that parentheses won't nest in this `P()` construct, change `.*` to `[^)]*`.

Edit: I also suggest that you look for a regex visualizer or debugger when you have a problem like this.  For example, pasting your example into debuggex.com makes it clear what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the *greediness* of the `*` quantifier. It matches as many times as it can, i.e. it doesn't stop at the first `)`.

You can try Perl, that features "non-greedy" (frugal, lazy) `*?`:

```
perl -pe 's/P\((.*?)\)\\mid\((.*?)\)/\\condprob{$1}{$2}/g'
```